# How check that associated file is not NULL in thinking sphinx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a `Product` model that `has_many :images`

Image model has a photo field (I use carrierwave gem to store the file):

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :photo, DressingUploader
end
```

Here is my `product_index.rb` file:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :product, with: :active_record do
  indexes name

  has images.pose, as: :image_pose

  join images
end
```

How can I add `images.photo` attribute to thinking sphinx which will check whether the photo is present or not?
I could add this line `where "images.photo IS NOT NULL"`, but I do not need the condition to work globally.

I tried to do something like

```
has "images.photo IS NOT NULL", as: :has_photo, type: :boolean
```

But it doesn`t work

Comment: Given you're dealing with many images, rather than just one… do you want to return products where there are no images? Or products that _do_ have images, but at least one of those images doesn't have a photo value?

Comment: @pat I want to get products with images where at least one photo is present (`IS NOT NULL`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're dealing with many images for a given product, you'll need to aggregate the photo values for each image. It could be that a SUM(CASE) statement will do the job (and this *should* work in both MySQL and PostgreSQL):

```
has "SUM(CASE WHEN images.photo IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) > 0",
  as: :has_photo, type: :boolean
```

This solution is fine for SQL-backed indices (which is what you're using). For anyone coming across this that is using real-time indices, then the solution is different… you'll want a method to refer to within your class:

```
def has_image_photos
  images.any? { |image| image.photo.present? }
end
```

And then in the index:

```
has has_image_photos, as: :has_photo, type: :boolean
```